# Zend Framework slow connect to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, connection

Using Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug and FirePHP to profile our code, all other queries after the connect is fast, but it seems to take forever for Zend Framework to establish a connection to mysql, I've googled the problem and others suggest using table metadata cache which I did, but the problem still persists.

```
ZendDbTableAbstract::setDefaultMetadataCache(ZendRegistry::get('cache'));
```

We're using ZF 1.7, php 5.2 and Mysql 5.1, please see the screenshot for more details.

[image: http://imgur.com/8FsgK.png]

I'm beginning to suspect this could be a Mysql configuration issue and I'm going to look into that now, but I do appreciate any ideas or suggestion regarding this problem, thanks.

Comment: First guess would be DNS - is the database on the same server as the application? If you connect to an IP address instead of hostname is there any difference?

Comment: Also try it with straight up `mysql_connect` and `mysql_query` and see if it's any different. Then you'll know which side of the fence the problem is on.

Comment: Yeah as UltimateBrent said try with mysql_connect. AFAIK there is nothing in Zend_Db that could slow it down other then to be waiting on something(MySQL server).